# Getting the column name in a table with just a single value

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use a single value (String or number) to search in a DB (close to 60000 rows and 20 columns) and retrieve the corresponding column name for the value. How do i do this without performing a complete search on the entire DB?

If table is as follows

```
Country | State       | Population
----------------------------------
USA     | Texas       | 100000
India   | Maharashtra | 200000
```

Using just the value 'Maharashtra', I want my program to understand that the column for maharashtra is 'State' and not Country or Population.

The data is stored inside a pandas data frame.

Comment: What database technology are you using? Where's your python that queries the DB?

Comment: How are you accessing the DB?  Are you connecting to some SQL server?  Do you have all of the data in memory?  If so, is it stored as a `dict`, as a `pandas.DataFrame`, etc?  There is not enough information here to answer the question.

Comment: So the data is stored inside a pandas data frame

Comment: I can't imagine a way to do that without any kind of inverse index.

Comment: I agree with OSainz, there really ins't a way to determine which column your data element belongs to unless you ping each column.  You can however take off some of the load by checking if the string is a String or Alphanumeric  (ergo use .isAlpha() ).

Answer (score 1):

Pandas : Rows filtered for matching search term in any columns

```
search = 'search term' 
df.loc[df.isin([search]).any(axis=1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

An inverse index might be the most performant solution if the data does not change often:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Country": ["USA", "India"],
    "State": ["Texas", "Maharashtra"],
    "Population": [100_000, 200_000],
})

# Create an inverse index - must be done only once:
inverse_map = pd.Series()
for idx, column in enumerate(df.columns):
    column_data = pd.Series(np.repeat(idx, len(df[column])), index=df[column])
    inverse_map = inverse_map.append(column_data)

# This should be fast - even for many queries:
df.columns[inverse_map.loc["Maharashtra"]]
# Output: 'State'
```

I work with indices in the inverse_map instead of column names to save memory.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it worked for me

`df.columns[(df.values=='Maharashtra').any(0)].tolist()`

the **df** is your DB in *Pandas.Dataframe* format

it returns a list which includes the name of the column

Comment: @crossemup Please check if my code is what you need. If so, please mark as the accepted answer. Cheers.